# Writing Google chrome extension that works on some urls

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want write a extension for google chrome works for example in this urls:

```
Site.com/page.php?v=([0-9])
```

In these pages extension fill a text field automically and send form.

How i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with jQuery:

1. Find text fields on the page and fill them:
   `$('input[name=somename]').val('<some value>');`
2. Call submit on the form:
   `$('form#someid').submit();`